# WCF: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. when hosting in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-client

I have a WCF service which is being hosted in IIS. I have a WCF client also (a console application). I have used `svcutil` to build the proxy class and configuration file and then added those to my client project. It built properly. But when I tried to run the program, it is throwing the below exception

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

//My client program code

```
namespace MyFirstWCFClient
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceClient objClient = new ServiceClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client calling the service....");

        string strName=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(objClient.HelloWorld("Shyju"));
        Console.Read();

    }
 }
}
```

Output.config file of my client is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/IISHostedserviceTest/Service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
     </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and in the web.config of my service has the below configuration

```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
    <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/IISHostedserviceTest/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I used this(http://www.wcftutorial.net/WCF-IIS-Hosting.aspx) tutorial to have a try on WCF.

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Maybe you should post the contents of both the service and the client app config files to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Quick question: if your client app is called `myclient.exe`, is your config in the same directory as the EXE and called `MyClient.exe.config` ?

You can't just take the `output.config` from `svcutil` - you will need to either add a `app.config` to your client console project (which will be renamed to `myclient.exe.config` when compiling), or you need to copy/rename the `output.config` to `myclient.exe.config` in order for your client app to find and use it.

Comment: Given a console app `app.exe`, is the only way for this app to find its corresponding config file `config.config` at runtime to rename it to `app.exe.config`? Isn't there a compiler flag to control this? (I'm just started out with C# and I'm trying to indulge myself in the *art* by creating apps and compiling them w/o Visual Studio - for to learn of course.)

Comment: @KohányiRóbert: You can manually load and parse the file - not recommended, though. BY default, renaming it to `app.exe.config` is the recommended (and only "automatically" working way), and there is no compiler switch or flag or anything to change that naming conventino, no.

Comment: The fact that this has a correct valid answer means this is not a "stupid" question. Please, @marc_s, language.

Comment: @IsaacLlopis: you've misinterpreted my response - I did **not** mean to claim the OP's question was stupid - far from it ....

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the constructor for the client that specifies the endpoint configuration name, eg.

```
objClient = new ServiceClient ("WSHttpBinding_IService");
```

That will tell the proxy to use the configuration you specified in the config file.

Comment: No Axel,The exception remains the same

Comment: Tried this... No luck :(

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with 2 WCF services connecting one to another.

After generating output.config + MyService.cs class files with the svcutil.exe and copying them to the solution dir I had the same problem.

Just found an answer to this problem: You have to copy whole "bindings" tag to your main config file inside "ServiceModel" tag AND copy your referenced endpoint next to existing endpoints in your main config file - that solved the exception problem for me

Comment: Your answer is really helpfull! I have two projects with WCF clients in one solution and the running project which use both of them. I have copied the whole binding from both of them to the running project and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to take would be to add a Service Reference to your IIS hosted service.  Visual Studio will automatically run svcutil in the background and do the configuration work for you - i.e. it'll create the app.config for you.

Doing it manually is fine, but I suggest running it at least once by adding a Service Reference just to see it work properly.