# WCF VSTO client cannot find default endpoint when deployed on win2k8

Tags: .net, wcf, vsto, windows-server-2008

I created and deployed a WCF client (launched from a VSTO Word Addin) on a Win2008R2 Terminal Server.
When excution the default constructor of the WCF proxy an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, stating that the default endpoint for the contract cannot be found.

The same WCF client when deployed to a Win7 x64 machine just runs fine using the same .dll.config

I tried to create an instance inside PowerShell and receive the same error.

If creating a dedicate endpoint in PowerShell I can excute a service method:

```
$binding = New-Object System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
$endpoint = New-Object System.ServiceModel.EndPointAddress("http://myserver:7777/CompanyService.svc")
$client = New-Object MyClient.CompanyServiceReference.CompanyServiceClient($binding, $endpoint)
$v = $client.Version()
```

**Service Web.config (part)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoHttpSecurity" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="CompanyService">
            <endpoint address="http://myserver:7777/mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" />
            <endpoint name="Version" address="http://myserver:7777/Version" contract="MyService.ICompanyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoHttpSecurity" />
            <endpoint name="CompanyList" address="http://myserver:7777/CompanyList" contract="MyService.ICompanyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NoHttpSecurity" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

**MyClient.dll.config (part)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICompanyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://myserver:7777/CompanyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICompanyService"
         contract="CompanyServiceReference.ICompanyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICompanyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I "fixed" this by copying my Client.config to the Office Program Folder and renaming it to WINWORD.EXE.config.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192970/wcfexception-could-not-find-default-endpoint-element-that-references-contract-i

Comment: @Roy: Not really a duplicate since I can confirm that a working configuration is in place.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We have exactly the same issue - instiantating wcf proxy client from excel addin and works fine when deployed on some machine win7 64 and xp 32 but not on other win7 64 and xp 32! Seems like its not picking up config as even if I screw with it on the machines which dont work then it doesnt seem to care - as if its not getting that far. Thanks

Comment: We got it "fixed" by copying our WCFClient.config to the Office Program Folder and renaming it to WINWORD.EXE.config. Deploying Add-Ins for all users is a real hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create an endpoint programmatically?

```
MyProxy proxy = new MyProxy (new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://server/Service.svc"));
```

If this works, then very probably it *is* a configuration issue.

Comment: Okay I tried creating a endpoint in PowerShell and could call a service method. I'll add my service and client configuration.

Comment: I'll accept that the actual issue is that the config obviously isn't read / isn't accessible and investigate on how to configure VSTO Addins.

Answer (score 9):

This issue is caused by the deployment project not having the correct entry in the registry for the manifest file. The workarounds above work because - having not found a config file for the add-in word/excel etc. look in the default location (their program directory) and look for the default config file name - in the case of MsWord WINWORD.EXE.config.

The incorrect form for the manifest entry is:

```
[TARGETDIR]Addin.vsto|vstolocal
```

It should be:

```
file:///[TARGETDIR]Addin.vsto|vstolocal
```

Then your config file will be loaded in correctly.

For more information see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653444/visual-studio-sp1-or-specifically-vsto-sp1-issue-with-config-file-location)

Comment: This looks interesting - I'll have to forward this to my successor since I did quit the company this march.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. For the config to be read properly, we need to use file:/// prefix and |vstolocal suffix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same problem with an Excel 2010 Addin we created via Visual Studio 2010 .NET4 .  We fixed our issue by following the updated fix in this post, but wanted to elaborate with the details of our fix, see below.

> **UPDATE**
>   I "fixed" this by copying my Client.config to the Office Program Folder and renaming it to WINWORD.EXE.config.

The details of our fix are the following:

1. Uninstalled our Excel 2010 Addin; then Reinstalled our Excel 2010 Addin via Windows Installer.
2. Opened the **$EXCEL_HOME** directory.  The **$EXCEL_HOME** directory is the directory where the Excel 2010 Office Program "Excel.exe" is located (For us on Windows 7 and XP - *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14*)
3. Copied our application/addin config ***"MyAddinProjName"***.dll.config (which was installed during the Excel Addin installation) from our installed Addin location (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft\"**MyAddinProjName**"*) to the **$EXCEL_HOME** directory
4. We then renamed ***"MyAddinProjName"***.dll.config it to "*Excel.exe.config*"
5. Jumped for joy after the error no longer appeared.

We never figured out why this happened on some machines and not others but we do know that this fix/work around allowed us to continue testing the Addin functionality.  Our solution to handle any installations of the Addin that present this problem is to provide a .bat or VB script that the System Admins can run which will copy and rename the config file to the appropriate locations.

I hope this information helps everyone with the same problem and clarifies any missing details :)